# GWT Application exception font doesnt exist

Tags: libgdx, awt

I'm building a html gwt but have a problem with font:
"GWTApplication : exception :font/fonttahoma/tahoma18.fnt does not exist
font/fontahoma/tahoma18.fnt does not exist"
but in asset in war folder have tahoma18.fnt.
Can you help me fix it?
I spent 3 days to search but no result .

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem.
The problem is loss file webconfig when I push "war" folder to server.